# rPi model B + MCP23017 + relay board. GPA0 pin low output not close enough to 0v to trigger relay

Tags: gpio, relay

I've setup a MCP23017 16-bit I/O expander with a rPi model B via i2c, and I am able to control components like LEDs on the channels GPA0-GPA7 using code like this;

```
# set GPA pins to output
i2cset -y 1 0x20 0x00 0x00

# set GPA0 pin to on, (led on)
i2cset -y 1 0x20 0x14 0x1
```

However what I want to do is control a 12V electromagnetic lock from a [relay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/200929489259), and though I am able to trigger the relay, its unreliable and setting a pin on the MCP23017 to LOW doesn't always trigger the relay.

The led on the relay board is dim, compared to when its manually triggered by putting IN2 to GND

The relay is triggered active-low, and the relay specs suggest 0-0.5V is required to trigger it.

```
# set GPA0 pin to on, (relay on)
i2cset -y 1 0x20 0x14 0x0
```

The circuit is currently setup like this with a relay instead of the led;
[image]

The relay however is triggered active-low, and so is looking for a Voltage between 0-0.5 Volts compared to ground.

However low-output on the MCP23017 GPA0 pin is measured at about 0.7 - 0.9 volts, and this doesn't appear to be low enough to trigger the relay.

The [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf) for the MCP23017 says that output-low should be less than 0.6 V. So at the very least the MCP23017 is out of spec.

The schematic from a similar relay board;
[image]

- 5V 2-Channel Relay interface board, and each one needs 15-20mA Driver Current

Comment: Are you powering the electromagnet from 12V?  Are you sure the 12V circuitry is isolated from the 5V Pi circuitry?  I.e. with no Pi 5V connected can you measure any voltage between VCC and ground.  Do you have/need a fly-back diode to prevent the back EMF from the collapsing electromagnet field getting back into the circuitry.  Have you considered using a ULN280X series chip?

Comment: For the purposes of isolation, I currently have 2 separate 5v supplies, and a 12V supply on different wal warts, so 3 wall sockets in all. Both the relay coil and the lock circuit should be isolated from back EMF.

Comment: I put some capacitors across the MCP23017 and I've not seen teh MCP23017 reset since. So I am going to edit the question to focus on the over voltage of the MCP23017 output.

Comment: When you leave the relay input at High-Z (such as when disconnected from the circuit), does it behave as triggered?

Comment: If the input to the relay is disconnected, the relay is not triggered.

Comment: That makes things a little bit harder. Are you sure the MCP23017 can source/soak the current the relay needs to trigger? 15-20mA from your question. You might have a current issue, and not a voltage issue here.

Comment: I think that 15-20 mA is the current that the relay coil draws. This is supplied by a dedicated 5v line. The GPA0 pin has to sink VCC/R5 worth of current to trigger the relay, and according to the datasheet MCP23017 can sink/source 25mA on an output pin.

Comment: The USB psu that is providing power for the MCP23017 is about 5.3V measured, and I think this is close to the top of the range for the MCP23017, which is why it is close to the top of its range for LOW on an output pin. I am going to try a diode or a resistor on the output pin, or MCP23017 Vdd to see if that brings it into the 0-0.5 V required by the relay.